# Wrong number of $4\times 4$ domino tilings, but why?

Tags: tiling

[From the internet](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DominoTiling.html), I know that a domino tiling of a $4\times4 $ checker board can be arranged in $36$ different ways.

With the following reasoning, I conclude that it must be $37$, which is one more than the correct result. Where is my mistake?

Tiling a $4\times 2$ or $2\times 4$ board can be done in $5$ ways, where

`--` is a horizontal domino and

`|`  is a vertical one:
`|`

```
||    ||    --    --    --
||    ||    --    --    ||
||    --    ||    --    ||
||    --    ||    --    --
```

Now, when you look at the $4\times 4$ board, you can find

$25$ tilings by arranging two $4\times 2$ tilings $x$ and $y$ side by side

```
xxyy
xxyy
xxyy
xxyy
```

$5$ tilings by combining a structure which is not present in the previous $25$ tilings with the $5$ different $2\times 4$ tilings (horizontal versions of the above $4\times 2$ tilings):

```
|--|
|--|
xxxx
xxxx
```

$5$ tiling  by putting the previous $5$ upside down

```
xxxx
xxxx
|--|
|--|
```

$2$ tiling of this kind:

```
|--|             ----
|||| and rotated |--|
||||             |--|
|--|             ----
```

$25 + 5 + 5 + 2 = 37$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doubled one is the following, which is present in both sets of 5 tilings:

```
|--|
|--|
|--|
|--|
```